# Does anyone get zero-height select fields in Firefox 3.6.3?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

If you open this HTML in Firefox 3.6.3 (confirmed in some earlier versions too), and click the drawStuff() link repeatedly, it doesn't render the contents of the last div consistently.  Looking more closely it seems like it's rendering select fields with height=0.  Any idea why this would happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title> A Page </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var num_select_options = 800;

      function drawStuff() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
          var foobar = document.getElementById('elem_' + i);
          while (foobar.childNodes.length >= 1) {
            foobar.removeChild(foobar.firstChild);
          }
          for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            var elem_select = document.createElement('select');
            for (var k = 0; k < num_select_options; k++) {
              elem_select.appendChild(new Option("Blah", k));
            }
            foobar.appendChild(elem_select);
          }          
        }
      }
    </script>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <table border=1 style="width:900px;" summary="A Table">
      <tr>
        <td> <div id="elem_0"></div> </td>
        <td> <div>abc</div>  <div id="elem_1"></div> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <a href="javascript:drawStuff()"> drawStuff() </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      drawStuff();
    </script>

  </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as it should for me.

The only strange thing I can see in the code is that you escape the "/" character in the closing tags, which isn't needed.

Comment: What version of Firefox were you using kaba?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce it. However, I see nothing particularly wrong in your code.

Just a guess... You are injecting large amounts of raw HTML in your page. Perhaps the browser cannot cope with it under certain circumstances. I think you could try a different approach: use DOM methods rather that `innerHTML`. Something like:

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.options.push( new Option("Blah", i) );
document.getElementById("elem_" + i).appendChild(select);
```

In my experience, browsers *sometimes* prefer this.

## Update

One more thing you can try: store all the raw HTML in a variable and perform the injection at once. Perhaps you can avoid issues related to asynchronous execution of DOM functions :-?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it out and updated the html above to reflect the changes.  Same result unfortunately.  There are so many strange things about this problem.  If you lower the 'num_select_options' value to much less than where it's at (800), the problem goes away.  If you get rid of the div with 'abc' in it, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the layout using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Is the height really 0? If so, use the other panes to figure out where it comes from. Maybe a user style sheet?

[EDIT] Where is the `form` element?

Also, you place an inline element (`select`) next to a block element (the `div` with `abc`). Try to create the `select` in a `div`.

If that also doesn't work, try to set the size of the `select` with CSS. Then report a bug against Firefox with your findings.

Comment: The height according to Firebug of the "select" fields is 0.  Not sure why.  There are no stylesheets or inline styles at all on the page.